# Floating DIVs causes relative DIVs below to be positioned wrongly

Tags: css

I have done this JS fiddle as an example:
[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/G7kdB/7/)

```
.column {
width: 100px;
height: 100%;
float: left;
```

}

You can see the yellow footer is not appearing below the floated column divs when the column divs have a height of 100%, but instead it is appearing in the same position.
If anyone can help me with this i would appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: your jsFiddle example doesn't contain a yellow footer

Comment: sorry did not update it, its updated now

Comment: It's alright, I already posted a solution mocking up my own footer. For reference on your link, here is the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/G7kdB/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a clear to your footer div:

```
clear: both;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G7kdB/8/